# UIPickerView UI and Functional issue in iPhone 6s plus device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uipickerview, uilocalnotification, ios9.3

I have created custom TimePicker using `UIPickerView`, taken 3 `UIPickerView`.

- One for Hours
- One for Minutes
- One for AM/PM

By picking time, I am using that time to set local notification. Because my application is based on alarm functionality.

UI part and Functional part works well in iPhone 5,5s,6,6 Plus but facing issue in iPhone 6s plus device.
Not getting what is going wrong! Same code works well in all other devices except iPhone 6s plus.

**Below screenshot is of iPhone 6,**

[image]

As you can see, ScreenShot time and PickerView time is same. It is functional part. I have written code like, catch the current time and as per that I have set the PickerView's selected index. Works perfect! Also I have set selected index fonts bigger. Which is also looks perfect in iPhone 6 device.

**Below screenshot is of iPhone 6s Plus,**

[image]

As you can see, ScreenShot time and `PickerView` time is not same. So functional part is not working in iPhone 6s plus device. Also in UI part, Fonts getting bigger for selected row in second `PickerView` but not in the first one.

Also when I set the local notification by picking time from time picker. It also works well (Notification gets fire on perfect time) in all other devices other than iPhone 6s plus. And in iPhone 6s plus whatever time I select from `UIPickerView`, notification gets fire immediately.

Don't know what is going wrong with iPhone 6s plus device. Either issue is with PickerView or something else. But why the same code works well for all other device and not only for iPhone 6s plus device.

Any help is appreciated! Badly stuck in this issue. Please help if anyone have any solution for this issue! Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

Please have a look in to my code...

**AddAlarmViewController.h**

```
@interface AddAlarmViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *arrHours;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *arrMinute;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *arrAP;


@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPickerHour;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPickerMinute;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPickerAP;
```

**AddAlarmViewController.m**

```
@interface AddAlarmViewController ()
{
    int countH,countM,countAP;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *strTime,*strTimeSlot;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDate *dateSelected;
@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger rowHour,rowAP,rowMinute;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *lblHour,*lblMinute,*lblAP;
@end

@implementation AddAlarmViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    countH = 0;
    countM = 0;
    countAP = 0;

    _arrHours = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6],[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:8],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],[NSNumber numberWithInt:12]];

    _arrMinute = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6],[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:8],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],[NSNumber numberWithInt:12],[NSNumber numberWithInt:13],[NSNumber numberWithInt:14],[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],[NSNumber numberWithInt:16],[NSNumber numberWithInt:17],[NSNumber numberWithInt:18],[NSNumber numberWithInt:19],[NSNumber numberWithInt:20],[NSNumber numberWithInt:21],[NSNumber numberWithInt:22],[NSNumber numberWithInt:23],[NSNumber numberWithInt:24],[NSNumber numberWithInt:25],[NSNumber numberWithInt:26],[NSNumber numberWithInt:27],[NSNumber numberWithInt:28],[NSNumber numberWithInt:29],[NSNumber numberWithInt:30],[NSNumber numberWithInt:31],[NSNumber numberWithInt:32],[NSNumber numberWithInt:33],[NSNumber numberWithInt:34],[NSNumber numberWithInt:35],[NSNumber numberWithInt:36],[NSNumber numberWithInt:37],[NSNumber numberWithInt:38],[NSNumber numberWithInt:39],[NSNumber numberWithInt:40],[NSNumber numberWithInt:41],[NSNumber numberWithInt:42],[NSNumber numberWithInt:43],[NSNumber numberWithInt:44],[NSNumber numberWithInt:45],[NSNumber numberWithInt:46],[NSNumber numberWithInt:47],[NSNumber numberWithInt:48],[NSNumber numberWithInt:49],[NSNumber numberWithInt:50],[NSNumber numberWithInt:51],[NSNumber numberWithInt:52],[NSNumber numberWithInt:53],[NSNumber numberWithInt:54],[NSNumber numberWithInt:55],[NSNumber numberWithInt:56],[NSNumber numberWithInt:57],[NSNumber numberWithInt:58],[NSNumber numberWithInt:59]];

    _arrAP = @[@"AM",@"PM"];

    [self.myPickerHour reloadAllComponents];
    [self.myPickerHour selectRow:_rowHour inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    [self.myPickerMinute reloadAllComponents];
    [self.myPickerMinute selectRow:_rowMinute inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    [self.myPickerAP reloadAllComponents];
    [self.myPickerAP selectRow:_rowAP inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}


#pragma mark - Picker View Data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        return [_arrHours count] * 100;
    } else if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
        return [_arrMinute count] * 100;
    } else {
        return [_arrAP count];
    }
}

#pragma mark- Picker View Delegate

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@" Row Number %ld", row % [_arrHours count]);
        _lblHour = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
        [_lblHour setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:70.0]];
        [_lblHour setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        NSLog(@"Print selected label of hour : %@",_lblHour.text);
        if (countH == 4) {
            isHour = TRUE;

            //------------------Above and Below Rows------------------//
            if (row > 0) {
                UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[pickerView viewForRow:row-1 forComponent:component];
                [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:16.0]];
                lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                lbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            }
            if (row < (_arrHours.count * 100)) {
                UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)[pickerView viewForRow:row+1 forComponent:component];
                [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:16.0]];
                lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                lbl1.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            }
            //-------------------------------------------------------//
        }

    } else if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
        _lblMinute = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
        [_lblMinute setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:70.0]];
        [_lblMinute setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        NSLog(@"Print selected label of minute : %@",_lblMinute.text);
        if (countM == 4) {
            isMinute = TRUE;

            //------------------Above and Below Rows------------------//
            if (row > 0) {
                UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[pickerView viewForRow:row-1 forComponent:component];
                [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:16.0]];
                lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                lbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            }

            if (row < (_arrMinute.count * 100)) {
                UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)[pickerView viewForRow:row+1 forComponent:component];
                [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:16.0]];
                lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                lbl1.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            }
            //-------------------------------------------------------//

        }

    } else if (pickerView.tag == 3) {

        _lblAP = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
        [_lblAP setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        NSLog(@"Print selected label of AP : %@",_lblAP.text);
    }
    NSLog(@"----------4");
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *str = [format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    int daysToAdd = 1;
    NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];

    [format setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *strHM = [format stringFromDate:now];

    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@ %@",_lblHour.text,_lblMinute.text,_lblAP.text];
    NSString *strSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@ %@",_lblHour.text,_lblMinute.text,_lblAP.text];
    if ([strHM isEqualToString:strSelected]) {
        [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        NSString *strWithOneDay = [format stringFromDate:newDate1];
        _strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",strWithOneDay,str1];
    } else {
        _strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",str,str1];
    }

    [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];
    _dateSelected = [format dateFromString:_strTime];

    if (!(_dateSelected == NULL)) {

        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:_dateSelected];
        NSInteger hour = [components hour];

        if(hour >= 3 && hour < 12) {
            _strTimeSlot = @"GOOD MORNING";
        }
        else if(hour >= 12 && hour < 17) {
            _strTimeSlot = @"GOOD AFTERNOON";
        }
        else if(hour >= 17 && hour < 20) {
            _strTimeSlot = @"GOOD EVENING";
        } else {
            _strTimeSlot = @"GOOD NIGHT";
        }
    }
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == 1 || pickerView.tag == 2) {
        return 70.0;
    }
    return 30.0;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *lblTitle = (id)view;

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
        [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];

        lblTitle= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
        [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:16.0]];
        lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrHours objectAtIndex:(row % [_arrHours count])]] length] == 1) {
            NSString *str = [@"0" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrHours objectAtIndex:(row % [_arrHours count])]]];
            lblTitle.text = str;
        } else {
            lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrHours objectAtIndex:(row % [_arrHours count])]];
        }
        if (row == _rowHour && !isHour) {
            countH++;
            [self pickerView:self.myPickerHour didSelectRow:_rowHour inComponent:0];
            _lblHour.text = lblTitle.text;
        }

    } else if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
        [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
        [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];

        lblTitle= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
        [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:16.0]];
        lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrMinute objectAtIndex:(row % [_arrMinute count])]] length] == 1) {
            NSString *str = [@"0" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrMinute objectAtIndex:(row % [_arrMinute count])]]];
            lblTitle.text = str;
        } else {
            lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrMinute objectAtIndex:(row % [_arrMinute count])]];
        }
        if (row == _rowMinute && !isMinute) {
            countM++;
            [self pickerView:self.myPickerMinute didSelectRow:_rowMinute inComponent:0];
            _lblMinute.text = lblTitle.text;
        }

    } else {
        [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
        [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];

        lblTitle= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
        [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:16.0]];
        lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblTitle.text = [_arrAP objectAtIndex:row];
        if (row == _rowAP) {
            [self pickerView:self.myPickerAP didSelectRow:_rowAP inComponent:0];
            _lblAP.text = lblTitle.text;
        }
    }
    return lblTitle;
}
```

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with the autolayout, if you are using that. Is there a constraint missing or extra? You could set the background color for the textfield to see if the font is smaller, or the whole view.

Comment: No, I am not using autolayout. I had managed it using Auto resizing. And there is not only UI issue. Facing functional issue as well in iPhone 6s plus.

Comment: iPhone 6s plus is device or simulator? And running which ios ? And other devices or simulator which works fine are running wich ios?

Comment: Can you show your storyboard.

Comment: No, I can't show full storyboard.

Comment: You could look at environmental factors... maybe it has something to do with the Locale of the 6s device? Did you already try another 6s device to see if it has the same issue, so you can isolate factors.

Comment: Could also be interesting to have a look at your code anyway. Can you post the bit where you update these elements?

Comment: Why can't you show the storyboard?  Right now you're just asking a question with images and no code.  It's impossible for us to know what is going on without more context.  If you can't show the storyboard or any code, please post or upload a standalone [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or sample project which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @JorisvanLiempdiDeveloper Please check my updated question. I have added whole code which I have written for Custom Time Picker(As in attached image)

Comment: @JAL Please check my updated question. I have added whole code which I have written for Custom Time Picker(As in attached image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for future readers, may be it will help someone somehow.

After doing a lot R & D and debugging the code, finally resolved my issue.

Code which I added in my current(check code of above question) code is as below,

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setLocale:locale];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

Before adding above lines of code(added these lines where ever I have used `NSDateFormatter`) it was working fine in all other devices except iPhone 6s plus. But by setting `NSLocale` and `TimeZone` to `NSDateFormatter` it is working perfectly fine in **ALL** devices.

Thanks!